# Random number generator with discrete probability distribution

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions, random

Is there a general algorithm for implementing a PRNG with a probability distribution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Mersenne Twister (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister)
to generate uniformly distributed random numbers first. It has a very
long period and other great properties. Alternatively, you could use
another uniformly distributed random number generator instead.

Suppose now you have generated a random number $x$ this way and that
the probability density you want to sample from is $\phi$. You need
to find $y$ s.t.
$$
x=\int_{-\infty}^{y}\phi\left(s\right)ds.
$$
In other words, if $\Phi$ is the cumulative distribution, you need
to find
$$
y=\Phi^{-1}\left(x\right).
$$
There are special cases in which you can make very fast algorithms
to do this. For example, for normally distributed random numbers,
there exists two methods:

- Box-Muller: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_muller
- Ziggurat (arguably better): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ziggurat_algorithm

Comment: There is an improvement on the Box-Muller algorithm by George Marsaglia called the [Marsaglia Polar Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marsaglia_polar_method). However,the Ziggurat algorithm is even more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you are talking about sampling a non-uniform discrete random variable.

The general method for univariate random variables is the [inverse transform sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling).

Alternatively, one can use a [rejection method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling).

For certain classes of univariate probability mass functions one can automatically build a hat distribution. See the book "[Automatic non-uniform random variate generation](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540406522)"

Also the book by J.E. Gentle "[Random Number Generation and Monte Carlo Methods](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387001786)" contains many algorithms for standard discrete distributions.

I would be amiss if I did not mention the [freely available](http://luc.devroye.org/rnbookindex.html) monograph by L. Devroye "Non-uniform random number generation".

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

One of the best resources for random variate generation is Luc Devroye's book **Non-Uniform Random Variate Generation** which he provides for free as a set of PDFs [here](http://luc.devroye.org/rnbookindex.html).